# Draw d observation from a sample n times and calculate the mean

Tags: r, resampling

Consider the following data:

```
x <- c(2, 4, 6, 8)
mean(x)
[1] 5
```

Now I want do draw `2` observations. This gives me `6` combinations. I want to calculate the mean for all `6` combinations, and the mean of these `6` values. That is, I should get the following means:

```
(2+4)/2 = 3
(2+6)/2 = 4
(2+8)/2 = 5
(4+6)/2 = 5
(4+8)/2 = 6
(6+8)/2 = 7
```

I know the order could be different from the above, but it should each time give me an average `5` (in the case above: `(3+4+5+5+6+7)/6 = 5`).

Can anyone help me?

Comment: You are looking for `combn`. Try `combn(x, 2, mean)`

Answer (score 0):

One Line answer:

```
mean(rowMeans(t(combn(x,2))))
```

explained step by step:

with 'draw 2 observations' you actually mean to select 2 objects/observations out of x:

```
x <- c(2, 4, 6, 8) 
combn(x, 2)
##      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
## [1,]    2    2    2    4    4    6
## [2,]    4    6    8    6    8    8
```

with `t()` you can transform it to:

```
t(combn(x,2))
##      [,1] [,2]
##  [1,]    2    4
##  [2,]    2    6
##  [3,]    2    8
##  [4,]    4    6
##  [5,]    4    8
##  [6,]    6    8
```

The means you can calculate by `rowMeans()`

```
rowMeans(t(combn(x,2)))
## [1] 3 4 5 5 6 7
```

If you calculate the mean of that, you get what you want.

```
mean(rowMeans(t(combn(x,2))))
## [1] 5
```

Comment: To get full combinations and not just m out of a vector, use `expand.grid(x, x)` but it was clear you didn't want a object to be allowed to be repeated in the observations, so this is `combn(<vector>, <how-many-out-of-vector-to-choose>)`

Answer (score 0):

I think OP was going in right-direction to use `sample` in order to draw `2` observations `n` times (as title suggests). But somehow angle of solution changed towards `combn` function (which is not a correct option).

An option is to use `sample` along with `replicate` as:

```
x <- c(2, 4, 6, 8)

mean(replicate(6, sample(x,2)))
#[1] 4.666667        #There is random-ness in set of observations selected.
```

In above attempt, `replicate` provides `6` sets of 2 observations as:

```
replicate(6, sample(x,2))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
# [1,]    2    4    4    4    8    8
# [2,]    6    2    2    8    6    2
```

Personally, I dont think `combn` is a correct option to use here. `combn` returns all possible combination of selected number of observations. That means, every observation (of `x`) will appear equal number of times in combination set received from `combn` function. This implies, that `mean` of `combn(x,2)` will be same as `mean(x)`. Hence, what's point using `combn` in this case.

Comment: No, `comb` is correct. . `combn()` is the mathematical combination `C ( n , r ) = n ! ( n − r ) ! r !`. What you thought that `combn()` is doing, actually `expand.grid()` is doing in R (I am talking about that in my comment to my answer).